# MAMP 1146 "Table Does Not Exist" Errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am seeing this error in MAMP for every table/database I have setup and can't seem to find a solution.

When I am in PHPMyAdmin I can see the tables of each database listed but in the Structure tab under Information they all show as having Data of 0B.

If I navigate to the relevant folders on my hard drive (Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/database_name/) I can see that I have .frm and .ibd files, which all have a file size which would suggest they contain data.

How do I get PHPMyAdmin to read the data from these files?

I really can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance for any tips/suggestions.